# how to add text and images together on a function load

Tags: javascript

I have a function in which when the function is called I need to have text and an image pop up. My javascript is:

```
 function Upload(){
 if(value !- ''){
      $("#divValue").html("Uploaded: " + //i need to add an image here );
 }
```

So where it says //I need to add an image here, this is where my image, lets say its tire.gif, needs to be added so when the javascript is called it displays the text and image together.

Comment: Have you tried adding an img tag to your string?

Comment: I tried $("<img src='../images/tire.gif' />") but that didn't work

Comment: @Keith: are you referencing the image correctly? (have you checked for any errors using a console such as chrome's)

Comment: Yeah nothing yet on the console that I can find

Comment: yeah none of these are working so far, ill have to keep trying I guess

Answer (score 2):

you can use document.createElement method to create a img Object and simply set the source and optional height and width, then add it to your div using "append":

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = //URL to your image

    $(img).css('width','50px'); //set the width  (optional)
    $(img).css('height','50px'); //set the height (optional)
```

//finally append the newly created image object to your "DivValue"

```
   $("#divValue").append(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
function Upload(){ 
  var value="some value";
  if(value != ''){     
    $("#divValue").html("Uploaded: <img src='../images/tire.gif' />" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty straight forward. You just need to pass the tag inside the string that will replace the html.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybz6f/)

But you just need to do:

`$("#divValue").html("Uploaded: <img src=' PATH_TO tire.gif ' /> ");`

Watch the difference between " and ' to avoid syntax problems.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
$("#divValue").html('Uploaded: ' + '<img src="image.jpg" alt=""/>');
```